# Is it possible to take high quality screen captures?

Tags: screenshot

I'm making a manual for a web-based app. I take screenshots and put them into
adobe illustrator and they lose their quality extremely fast when zooming in.

**Is there any way I can take high resolution or vector based screenshots that don't loose image quality when zoomed in?** This seems to be only a problem with Illustrator, with Photoshop when I zoom in it gets slightly fuzzy but that's it.

Comment: Is the problem that you'd want nearest neighbor interpolation instead of the cubic interpolation you get? This is typically the problem people describe without knowing it.

Comment: There is a paper with some ideas: Mikheev, S.M. and Kurilin, I.V. and Vil’kin, A.M. and Rychagov, M.N. and Lee, HoKeun and Kim, SangHo and Choi, DonChul
Improving the print quality of screenshots
*Pattern Recognition and Image Analysis*
October 2015, Volume 25, Issue 4, pp 674-684 http://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1054661815040173?no-access=true#

Answer (score 13):

There's no way to capture a vector screenshot. You can, however, convert the screenshot to vector through use of tools like Image Trace (Illustrator, under the Window menu) or recreate the user interface by hand.

Alternatively, if you have access to a computer (or tablet) with a retina display, the screenshots taken on it will be around double the resolution and be able to be scaled up a lot cleaner. They will, however, still be raster graphics, so they won't scale infinitely.

The reason why it gets fuzzy and why you can't take a vector screenshot: Screenshots are always [raster graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics). Illustrator is a vector graphics program. Raster graphics are pixel-based; they're comprised of many pixels that each have color information. When you scale a raster image up, you make the pixels bigger, which results in a pixelated or fuzzy look to the image.

[Vector graphics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) are essentially math and some markup. When you create a shape in Illustrator, it makes a mathematical expression that represents that shape. When you scale the image, it just redraws it. It doesn't get pixelated because the shape is preserved in the expression, not in the color value of the pixels.

When you take a screenshot, you're literally capturing the pixels on your screen, so its a raster, or bitmapped, image and not a vector.

Answer (score 7):

This is a common question that I like to try and push back on:

> don't bother

A screen shot is literally that...what the user would see on screen. There is no need to make it any higher resolution or sharper than it is. It is what it is and that is what you should show the user.

In other words: It's fine. Just leave it! :)

That said, the lazy solution: If you can run the software or web site on a Retina MacBook, use that, as your screen shot will contain 4x the pixels by default.

If the issue, on the other hand, is that your images are getting fuzzy in software they are being imported into, the issue is potentially that the images are being converted to JPG and resampled. This is common when making PDFs. A workaround for that would be:

- save screen shots as PNG files by default--not JPGs
- Make sure your image import settings (or, if PDF, your image compression settings) are set to

  - do *not* resample
  - do *not* convert to JPG

Comment: I don't import my shots but just cut and paste them.

Comment: @A90'skid cut and paste into what?

Comment: Into the adobe ai page I'm working on in illustrator.

Comment: are you resizing in AI? What are your export settings set as? What are you saving the AI file as? A PDF?

Comment: No resizing. I'm saving them as a pdf. I'm not sure what my export settings are but I'm not exporting anything.

Comment: You are. You are saving (exporting) to PDF. :) I don't have AI in front of me but somewhere in AI's settings or within the export options screens you should be able to check for the PDF settings that I mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can enlarge the content *before* you take a screen shot by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> on Windows. This is easier than seeking out a retina computer at times.

Comment: Those are not universal shortcuts. They also do not enlarge anything: they _zoom in_ (making content larger, but leaving menus and other non-content, erm, content at its original size). On a Mac, enlarging is done by scrolling up while holding down `Alt`.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, did the default change? I thought it was Ctrl, but it could just be that my system is configured differently.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:
Maximise the size of the image you're taking a screenshot of; make it fill the screen as much as you can.

Use 'Snipimage' to exactly fit the image you want.
(Start > All Programs > Accessories ... & I recommend pinning it to the taskbar where it's conveniently there when you want it)

Click File> Send to> Email recipient as attachment

Drag the attachment from the email which opens into a directory so you've got a copy of it.

Close the email.

Now try putting this image into powerpoint (or word, or whatever). It behaves much better than the original screenshot.

Comment: This will still leave the screenshot only as large as the screen itself (in pixels)